# Create a popup window in MediaWiki

Tags: php, css, popup, mediawiki

I am customising [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for our internal portal.

I need to open a popup window on clicking a link in the wikitext. This popup would take information from the [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database and display a movie clip or a document or something.

How can this be done?

Comment: Depends on how what exactly you want to do, flexible you want it to be and how much effort you are willing to put into it - you should give more information.

Comment: Which extension did you use, in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Popup_extensions

Answer (score 1):

You've probably considered this but just to be sure - many people really hate popups which is why modern browsers have pop up blockers. So, if you use them, you'll have to include browser specific instructions on how to enable pop ups.

As an alterative, I suggest you embed the movie clip / document - using e.g. an [iFrame](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3AWebsite_in_iFrame).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is very valid. The requirement is specifically to display the content in a pop up window.

Comment: @Karthick - a client side solution (at least for video) is also possible but tricky - you can recommend people use a certain video viewer which is launched from their browser. Only worth considering if Jan's suggestion (or iFrame) doesn't help.